# How can make single row by using python?

Tags: python, regex, row

Each observation has so many lines. The Header always with all the row. 
It is a huge text file. The Sample input is like given below:

```
time: 2017-12-24 13:13:34 +0000; A: 61792; B: (
60328,
60344,
60344,
60344
); C: (
"-3672",
"-3656",
1547,
1578
); D(
1500,
1484,
1500,
); E: (
313,
328
)
time: 2017-12-25 13:13:35 +0000; A: 6134; B: (
628,
60374,
6044
); C: (
"-72",
"6",
157,
157
); D(
1700,
1654,
1580,
); E: (
3103,
3208
)
```

The output in rows which like :

```
time A B C D E
2017-12-24 13:13:34 +0000;  61792;  ( 60328;60344;60344;60344); (-3672;-3656;1547; 1578 ); (1500;1484;1500);  (313;328)
2017-12-25 13:13:35 +0000;  6134; (628;60374;6044;0000); (-72;6;157;157); (1700;1654;1580); (3103;3208)
```

I want to pass the txt file as input and get a csv file as output. How can I do that with python using the regular expression?

Comment: Why regex!? A `for` loop is sufficient?

Comment: Use [`[\r\n]|(time):\s*|([a-z]+):?\s*(?=[(\d])|"([\d-]+)"|,\s*(?=\))` replace with `$3`](https://regex101.com/r/xNa33M/2) and then use the capture groups to reconstruct the output where each line is split by locations where capture group 1 was caught

Comment: Do you want in csv  or in terminal ?

Comment: Its a pandas dataframe. I want csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this solution if you want by regex:

[Live Demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/G7IMvB/3)

```
import re
import collections

pattern='((?<=time:.).*?(?=;))|((?<=A:.).*?(?=;))|((?<=B:.\().*?(?=\)))|((?<=C:.\().*?(?=\)))|((?<=D\().*?(?=\)))|((?<=E:.\().*?(?=\)))'
string_1="""time: 2017-12-24 13:13:34 +0000; A: 61792; B: (
60328,
60344,
60344,
60344
); C: (
"-3672",
"-3656",
1547,
1578
); D(
1500,
1484,
1500,
); E: (
313,
328
)
time: 2017-12-25 13:13:35 +0000; A: 6134; B: (
628,
60374,
6044
); C: (
"-72",
"6",
157,
157
); D(
1700,
1654,
1580,
); E: (
3103,
3208
)"""

match=re.finditer(pattern,string_1,flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
print('A B C D E Time')
print('----------------')
dict_1={}
for i in match:
    if i.group(1):
        if 'time' not in dict_1:
            dict_1['time']=[i.group(1)]
        else:
            dict_1['time'].append(i.group(1))
    if i.group(2):
        if 'A' not in dict_1:
            dict_1['A']=[i.group(2)]
        else:
            dict_1['A'].append(i.group(2))

    if i.group(3):
        if 'B' not in dict_1:
            dict_1['B']=[i.group(3).split()]
        else:
            dict_1['B'].append(i.group(3).split())

    if i.group(4):
        if 'C' not in dict_1:
            dict_1['C']=[i.group(4).split()]
        else:
            dict_1['C'].append(i.group(4).split())

    if i.group(5):
        if 'D' not in dict_1:
            dict_1['D']=[i.group(5).split()]
        else:
            dict_1['D'].append(i.group(5).split())

    if i.group(6):
        if 'E' not in dict_1:
            dict_1['E']=[i.group(6).split()]
        else:
            dict_1['E'].append(i.group(6).split())


sorted = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict_1.items()))

for i in zip(*sorted.values()):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
A B C D E Time
----------------
('61792', ['60328,', '60344,', '60344,', '60344'], ['"-3672",', '"-3656",', '1547,', '1578'], ['1500,', '1484,', '1500,'], ['313,', '328'], '2017-12-24 13:13:34 +0000')
('6134', ['628,', '60374,', '6044'], ['"-72",', '"6",', '157,', '157'], ['1700,', '1654,', '1580,'], ['3103,', '3208'], '2017-12-25 13:13:35 +0000')
```

Comment: Its a huge text file, I tried to pass the file as string_1 and output also tried to save as txt file but it does not work. There is error message "'OrderedDict' object is not callable "

Comment: How did you pass the file , i gave you answer on which data you provided , If you have to access data from file , you have to mention it and show sample of data from file .